# Birds of a feather in Münich?

Tags: discussion

I think it would be really cool if this little corner of the Drupal community would gather up and meet every now and then, and since we have our Cons and Camps, that seems like a perfect opportunity.

I think it's extra important since this site is largely cut off from d.o, and it would be very sad to "fork" the community needlessly.

I propose we pick a [BoF](http://munich2012.drupal.org/program/bofs) space during DrupalCon Münich, and meet each other face to face. We can't actually book space until in August, so this will remain theoretical until then. No harm in bringing it up early though. :)

Comment: If I can get my boss to pay for the ticket I'm there ;)

Comment: Make a good case for it! It's a very good opportunity to learn and network :)

Comment: I'll be there and can try to join.

Comment: Lots of bucks for this conf. Although i have just about 60km to drive to München. :)

Comment: @Volker, that's what you have employers/a sponsor for ;)

Comment: @Letharion, as a freelancer i have to ask myself for sponsoring. But hey, we'll see what I say... ;)

Comment: Not true, @Volker. I'm a freelancer and I usually ask clients to sponsor my flights to DrupalCamps (never been to DCon yet).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, mind the emoticons: http://munich2012.drupal.org/content/drupal-stackexchangers-d

Comment: Can we get this promoted somehow?