# Drupal.SE's Birthday Celebration

Tags: discussion

Did you know Drupal’s anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **30 August**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Answer (score 2):

What about a party after meeting at DrupalCon Munich? I've scheduled a Birds of Feather meetup tuesday morning: http://munich2012.drupal.org/content/drupal-stackexchangers-d (see [Birds of a feather in Münich?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/birds-of-a-feather-in-munich/1035) for original BOF proposal).

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion. To bad so few of us showed up.

Comment: i got to know berdir and i think googletorp was around as well

Comment: Propose this in a question: "Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details."